# rtcmem seems not to survive node restarts, as it should

Tags: lua, nodemcu

If you are using rtcmem to store values that you want to keep after a node restart, you may find that after a node restart values stored in slots 1 to 9 goes to 0, instead maintaining the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem only happens if you are using rtcmem slots 0 to 9 and you have in place the rtctime module, that require slots 0 to 9. Other slots works as expected.

If you do not have rtctime, you can use slots 0 to 9 without problems.

If you are using rtcfifo module, there are other dependencies.

From my point of view, this dependencies of other modules should be documented in rtcmem module.

Comment: "should be documented" - it _is_: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/rtctime/

Comment: I don't agree with you. if you are not using rtctime, you may miss the fact that  slots 0 to 9 of rtcmem are reserved for rtctime usage (and some other for rtcfifo). This is what happened to me: I loaded rtctime for future use, and the behavior of rtcmem changed. This dependencies should be documented in rtcmem docs.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. PR to that end are more than welcome.